# How to iterate ListObjectOne over the ListObjectTwo usring stream Java 8

Tags: java, stream, using

I have two different lists the first one is list and the second one is List
List studentList = new ArrayList<>();
List moduleList = new ArrayList<>();

How can I iterate the modulList over studentList so that you can see which student has passed for which Module;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsX2F.png)

class Student {

```
private String studentId;
private String name;
private Type gender;
private String studClass;
private String education;
private HashMap<String, Module> faillOrPass;

public Student()
{
    faillOrPass = new HashMap<String, Module>();
}

public Student (String studentId, String name, Type gender, String studClass, String education)
{
    faillOrPass = new HashMap<String, Module>();
    setStudentId(studentId);
    setName(name);
    setGender(gender);
    setStudClass(studClass);
    setEducation(education);
}

public enum Type { MALE, FAML}

// getters and setters
// equals() and hashCode()
// toString()
```

}

class Module {

```
String modulecode;
int grade;
int year;

public Module(String code, int year) {
    setModule(code);
    setYear(year);
    setGrade(-1);
}

// getters and setters
// equals and hashCode
// toString
```

}
public class TestClass {

```
final static Student st = new Student();
static String ZAYNUL = st.setVolledigeNaam("Zaynul Zaini");
static String PIPO = st.setVolledigeNaam("Pipo");
static String SANNY = st.setVolledigeNaam("Sanny Saniwich");
static String JOHAN = st.setVolledigeNaam("Johan Ginger");
static String DURSAH = st.setVolledigeNaam("Dursah Pikobillo");
static String ROMAN = st.setVolledigeNaam("Roman Romanawich");
static String TOM = st.setVolledigeNaam("Johonson");
static String ANDRE = st.setVolledigeNaam("Andersons");

public static List<Vak> getModuleList() {
    return List.of(

            new Vak(ZAYNUL, "IT", 8, 2020),
            new Vak(SANNY, "IT", 10, 2019),
            new Vak(ROMAN, "IT", 9, 2018),
            new Vak(MALIKA, "IT", 8, 2017),
            new Vak(DURSAH,"IT", 10, 2016),
            new Vak(PIPO,"IT", 10, 2020),

            new Vak(PIPO,"IPC", 5, 2020),
            new Vak(ZAYNUL,"IPC", 6, 2019),
            new Vak(SANNY,"IPC", 4, 2018),
            new Vak(ROMAN,"IPC", 1, 2017),
            new Vak(MALIKA,"IPC", 5, 2016),
            new Vak(DURSAH,"IPC", 4, 2020));
}

public static List<Student> getStudentList() {
    List<Student> listVak = new ArrayList<>();
    listVak.add(new Student("011", ZAYNUL, Student.Type.MALE, "first year", "Architecture"));
    listVak.add(new Student("012", MALIKA, Student.Type.FEMALE, "second year", "economics"));
    listVak.add(new Student("013", SANNY, Student.Type.FEMALE, "third year", "IT"));
    listVak.add(new Student("014", ROMAN, Student.Type.MALE, "fourth year", "Astronomy"));
    listVak.add(new Student("015", TOM, Student.Type.MALE, "second year", "economics"));
    listVak.add(new Student("016", ANDRE, Student.Type.FEMALE, "third year", "IT"));
    listVak.add(new Student("017", JOHAN, Student.Type.MALE, "fourth year", "Astronomy"));
    return listVak;
}

public static void  getPassedAndFaillModule(List<Student> listSt, List<Module> listVak) {

    List<Student> filteredList = listSt.stream()
            .filter(student -> listVak.stream()
                    .filter(md -> md.getCijfer() > 5)
                    .anyMatch(mdo -> mdo.getStudentName() !=null
                            && student.getVolledigeNaam().equals(mdo.getStudentName())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    filteredList.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Print the result: ");
    getPassedAndFaillModule(getStudentList(), getModuleList());
}
```

}

This is the result which I get but is not good.

Print the result:
StudentImpl{studentnummer='011', volledigeNaam='Zaynul Zaini', type='MALE', klaas='first year', studierichting='Architecture', vakkenLijst={}}

StudentImpl{studentnummer='012', volledigeNaam='Malika Ginger', type='FEMALE', klaas='second year', studierichting='economics', vakkenLijst={}}

StudentImpl{studentnummer='013', volledigeNaam='Sanny Saniwich', type='FEMALE', klaas='third year', studierichting='IT', vakkenLijst={}}

StudentImpl{studentnummer='014', volledigeNaam='Roman Romanawich', type='MALE', klaas='fourth year', studierichting='Astronomy', vakkenLijst={}}

Answer (score 0):

Main problem here is incomplete parts of code which fail to represent [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), relevant classes and parts are missing (e.g., `StudentImpl` and `vakkenLijst`, `Vak`).

The following refactoring may be needed:

- in class `Student` provide list of modules (maybe instead of redundant `failOrPass` map) and include it into `toString()` method:

```java
class Student {
    private List<Module> modules;

    public List<Module> getModules() {
        return this.modules;
    }
    public void setModules(List<Module> list) {
        this.modules = list;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + ": " + modules;
    }
}
```

- implement copy-like constructor in `Module` from an instance of `Vak` class:

```java
class Module {

    String module;
    int grade;
    int year;

    public Module(Vak vak) {
        this(vak.getModule(), vak.getGrade(), vak.getYear());
    }

    public Module(String code, int grade, int year) {
        setModule(code);
        setGrade(grade);
        setYear(year);
    }
// getters/setters/etc.

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Module: %s, grade=%d, year=%d", module, grade, year);
    }
}
```

- Rename method `getPassedAndFaillModule` - the getter should not have `void` return type:

```java
public static void fillVakDataForStudents(List<Student> students, List<Vak> vaks) {
    students.forEach(s ->
        s.setModules(
            vaks.stream()
                //.filter(v.getGrade() > 5) // optionally filter by grade
                .filter(v -> v.getStudentName().equals(s.getName()))
                .map(Module::new) // using copy-like constructor
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
        )
    );
    students.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Then for the shortened test data (without unnecessary details of `Student`) the result is as follows:

```java
static String ZAYNUL = "Zaynul Zaini";
static String PIPO = "Pipo";
static String SANNY = "Sanny Saniwich";
static String JOHAN = "Johan Ginger";
static String DURSAH = "Dursah Pikobillo";
static String ROMAN = "Roman Romanawich";
static String TOM = "Johonson";
static String ANDRE = "Andersons";

public static List<Vak> getVakList() {
    return List.of(
        new Vak(ZAYNUL, "IT", 8, 2020),
        new Vak(SANNY, "IT", 10, 2019),
        new Vak(ROMAN, "IT", 9, 2018),
        new Vak(JOHAN, "IT", 8, 2017),
        new Vak(DURSAH,"IT", 10, 2016),
        new Vak(PIPO,"IT", 10, 2020),

        new Vak(PIPO,"IPC", 5, 2020),
        new Vak(ZAYNUL,"IPC", 6, 2019),
        new Vak(SANNY,"IPC", 4, 2018),
        new Vak(ROMAN,"IPC", 1, 2017),
        new Vak(JOHAN,"IPC", 5, 2016),
        new Vak(DURSAH,"IPC", 4, 2020)
    );
}

public static List<Student> getStudentList() {
    return List.of(
        new Student("011", ZAYNUL),
        new Student("012", PIPO),
        new Student("013", SANNY),
        new Student("014", ROMAN),
        new Student("015", TOM),
        new Student("016", ANDRE),
        new Student("017", JOHAN),
        new Student("018", DURSAH)
    );
}

// calling test method
fillVakDataForStudents(getStudentList(), getVakList());
```

Output:

```
Zaynul Zaini: [Module: IT, grade=8, year=2020, Module: IPC, grade=6, year=2019]
Pipo: [Module: IT, grade=10, year=2020, Module: IPC, grade=5, year=2020]
Sanny Saniwich: [Module: IT, grade=10, year=2019, Module: IPC, grade=4, year=2018]
Roman Romanawich: [Module: IT, grade=9, year=2018, Module: IPC, grade=1, year=2017]
Johonson: []
Andersons: []
Johan Ginger: [Module: IT, grade=8, year=2017, Module: IPC, grade=5, year=2016]
Dursah Pikobillo: [Module: IT, grade=10, year=2016, Module: IPC, grade=4, year=2020]
```

Comment: Alex thank you very much you have helped me a lot.
Your solution works perfectly.

Comment: @TheRealKing you welcome! Please read the article at SO Help Center [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), thanks!